# create a 3d numpy array from a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2d numpy array as : `arr= np.array([[2,5,10],[6,2,9]])`. Now I want to convert this into 3d numpy array as I will place same number of 1's towards z-axis or the 3rd dimension, at that place replacing the element. For example, in place of 2, we will place two 1's and all other elements will be zero. So I place of two 1 and eight 0, since the matrix will be of size 2*3*10.

Is it possible? If yes, How can we achieve this?

Comment: Probably possible, but I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Please, add an example of what you want to get. It's difficult to understand otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this :

```
arr3d= np.zeros((arr.shape[0] , arr.shape[1], max(map(max, arr))))
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
        print(i,j,arr[i][j])
        for k in range(arr[i][j]):
            arr3d[i,j,k]=1
```

I know 3 loops :\

edited after suggestions from @hpaulj

Comment: Until we have a clearer idea of what he's trying to do, your 3 loops are better than nothing.  But when indexing a 3d array we prefer to use the `arr3d[i, j, k]` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're asking...

Use numpy.reshape. This takes the array and reshapes it like so:

array = numpy.array([[1,4,1], [3, 1, 4]])
numpy.reshape(array, (array.shape[0], array.shape[1], 1).

array is now numpy.array([[[1,4,1], [3, 1, 4]]])

The 1 at the end is basically adding an extra dimension to the array. Shape just means the length of an X-Y-Z-whatever dimensional thing...

See the numpy docs for reshape at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Use broadcasting like so:

```
>>> x = np.array([[2,5,10],[6,2,9]])
>>> 
>>> (x[..., None] > np.arange(10)).view('i1')
array([[[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]]], dtype=int8)
```